# Regular expression matching non-empty quoted substrings

Tags: regex, quotes, regex-group

I'm looking for a regular expression that matches `"batz"`, but not `""` in this text: `bla "" and "batz" foo`

`/"([^"]*)"/g` matches both, `/"([^"]+)"/g` matches `" and "`.

Is this even possible with regular expressions?

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Specifically I'm targeting .NET Regular Expressions. Any other flavour will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a captured group:

```
(?:""|[^"])*("[^"]+")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PUqGQ5/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `""`: Match `""`
  - `|`: OR
  - `[^"]`: Match any character that is not `"`
- `)*`: Close non-capture group. `*` lets this group match 0 or more occurrences
- `("[^"]+")`: Match a non-empty double quoted string and capture in group #1